# annotation in google bar chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bar-chart

I don't see annotations in my google charts.
Here is the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/sn37vp58/1/

```
   google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

                        ['Status', 'Completed', 'In Progress', 'Registered / Not Started','Past Due',{role: 'annotation'}],     

                        ['Safety',100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,'Hello'],['Conduct ',100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,'Hello'],['Policy',100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,'Hello'],['Privacy',100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,'Hello'],['Violence',100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,'Hello'],['Integrity',0.0,0.0,100.0,0.0,'Hello']

                         ]);    

                        var options = {

                height: 500,
                            width:  500,
                            chartArea:{left:100,top:100,right:0,bottom:0},
                            hAxis: { ticks: [25,50,75,100] },
                            isStacked: true,
                            bar: {groupWidth: '20'},
                            vAxis:{textStyle:{color: '#000000',fontSize: '12', paddingRight: '0',marginRight: '0'}},
                            colors: ['green','#ffff99','#ffbf0c','red'],
                            legend: { position: 'top'   },
annotations: {
          alwaysOutside: false,
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 17,
            auraColor: '#eee',
            color: '#eee'
          }}, 
                         };


      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(
        document.getElementById('ex5'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I am using google visualization bar chart to display the bar chart but annotations are missing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the annotations.alwaysOutside to true will make them show up.
[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VeldMuijz/sn37vp58/2/)

```
      alwaysOutside: true,
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 17,
        auraColor: 'none',
        color: '#555'
      }
```

Comment: @VeldMujiz.Anyidea as how  I can set get rid of the textshadow(white around the black text)http://jsfiddle.net/sn37vp58/3/

Comment: Yes. Setting the `highContrast` to `true` and setting the `auraColor` to `none` see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VeldMuijz/sn37vp58/4) and the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Configuration_Options)